# Paragraph ignores style because of another nested paragraph

Tags: html, css

Probably my CSS knowledge is limited, but I don't uderstand this:

```
<p style="color: green">
    <p style="color: red">This is red</p>
    This should be green. But it's not.
</p>
```

The second line will render in black ignoring the "color:green". Why?
I tested it in Chrome 28 and Firefox 22.

Comment: Should also be noted, you could get to the root of the problem if you had inspected result in browser. Inspection tools are now available for for all major browsers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't nest paragraphs.

Paragraph is an auto-closing element, the `</p>` is optional - any block element will automatically close the last open `<p>`.

**This is what's happening:**

```
<p style="color: green">
</p> <!-- auto-closed paragraph -->

<p style="color: red">
    This is red
</p>

This should be green. But it's not.

</p> <!-- here you have syntax error -->
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to nest a div inside the paragraph with the same effect. It looks like the paragraph gests closed not only with a paragraph but by any block element. Also tried to nest an h1 in an h1 and the result was the same as with the paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, I tried too and it looks like like that - any **block element** closes a paragraph. Let me correct the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot nest `<p>`'s. A paragraph's end tag may be omitted if it's followed with another paragraph. This means that in your code, the first paragraph contains no text, the second one contains "This is red". Then there is some text "This should be green. But it's not." which has no style and a closing `</p>` tag, which has no opening tag.

check: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

Answer (score 1):

Paragraph can't be nested within another paragraph or block element.

When your code is rendered in the browser it is rendered as like below

```
    <p style="color: green"></p>
    <p style="color: red">
      This is red
    </p>
    This should be green. But it's not.
    <p></p>
```

So you can see, there is no wrapper to the last sentence as a result the default css color i.e black is being applied on that.