# How to figure out what is the right target to put in CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried my best figuring out how to target that area. I want that ul to not have any bullets or squares and also the font to be black in color.

I tried this css code but it is not working

```
.footer-wrapper .section-list > li > a {
    color: #000;
}
```

For example this is my code..

```
<section id="footer">
        <div class="footer-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <p class="section-list">
                            <ul>
<!-- I am trying to target this part -->
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: If you dont want the bullets, why use a list, you could just use <br> to order your elements

Comment: Oh, why didn't i think of that. Dumb me!! But i also want to learn how to reference properly, in case if I need to know this in future

Comment: @John, I recommend sticking with a list if you're creating a list of items.  It's easier to maintain, it's more readable, and easier to style if you want to.

Comment: i would recomend using a tutorial, maybe codecademy, as it takes more than a quick answer to learn. For reference, you just write each child element after its perent (can be name or element or id/class).

Comment: also, while it is easyer to maintain and add to a list, removing the bullets is a harder problem in its self, and so is likely to overcomplicate a simple issue.

Comment: (i don't like using table but) tables could be used as well to format emements with no visible markers or boxes, and is easy to maintain/ add to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>` is for direct descendants, which is probably why you're not seeing anything

the direct descendant of `.section-list` is a `ul` not a `li`, so the style will never be applied.

So remove the `>` from the css selector and you'll be on the right track

```
.footer-wrapper .section-list  li  a {
    color: #000;
}
```

As far as removing the bullet, I recommend reading this little tutorial

http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_style2/index.html

the property you want to target is `list-style-type`

So, something like this would help.

```
.footer-wrapper .section-list  li { 
      list-style-type:none; 
      }
```

Edit: also, keep in mind that the selector you have for color only applies to any anchors inside of a list item.  If you want to make any text black, you also need to add the color to the second style that I added in my answer.

Edit 2:  You have to change `<p>` to `<div>`

`p` elements auto close with the next blocking element.  `ul` is a blocking element.

Which means, even though you didn't tell it to, the paragraph closes before the unordered element opens, so any style you apply to the paragraph never actually gets to any part of the list.

Changing the paragraph to a div is the best and quickest way to fix it.

You can read more about this behavior in this SO question:[Paragraph ignores style because of another nested paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032366/paragraph-ignores-style-because-of-another-nested-paragraph)

Comment: I just tried the first set of code and sadly, they did not turn black. and the second code, my bullets are not removed :( im really trying to understand this referencing of css well. So as to go ahead with my stuffs easier

Comment: Ah, it's because you have everything nested in a `p`.  Change the `p` to a `div` and it should work.  Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/AEd75/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Smeegs. Now I should start learning how to reference things properly :)

Comment: It's a learning process.  It can be tedious, but I would recommend picking up a book on CSS.  Take it from somebody who didn't, and did things the hard way only because it was the only way I knew.

Answer (score 2):

`li` is not a direct descendant of `.section-list`. `ul` is the direct descendant...

```
.footer-wrapper .section-list > ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-wrapper .section-list > ul li > a {
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just that ul tag, why not an id?

```
#ul_id > li {
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the bullets from a list, you need to apply this CSS to `ul`:

```
.footer-wrapper .section-list > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Plus, `>` operator means "direct child", so it cannot be used to select `li` from your div `section-list`.

Comment: Could you please explain why this is good solution to the problem.

Comment: While this could help, it is not useful to the OP unless you explain how it is used and what it does

Comment: You're right, I should have explained my answer instead of throwing it in a hurry. Thanks for the advice!